# NSOpenPanel not opening all the time?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

OK, this is my issue :

- I have an application with one window (an `NSPanel` actually)
- I'm trying to open and `NSOpenPanel` and get some input
- I may have to push the trigger button like 2-3 times, before it opens up...

**This is my code :**

```
- (IBAction)doExport:(id)sender 
{
    NSOpenPanel *openPanel  = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
    [openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

    NSInteger rezult = [openPanel runModal];

    if (rezult == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
        NSString* dir = [[openPanel URL] path];

        // do the processing here

    }

}
```

What's going on???

Comment: Is anything written to the console when it fails? What is `rezult` set to when it fails? Or is your action not even called?

Comment: @user1118321 Nope, nothing is written to the console. The `rezult` variable gets zero. If I add a `while (rezult==0) { result=[openPanel runModal]; }` then it works, but it keeps opening panels, even when one is closed... :-S Any ideas?

Comment: @user1118321 hmmm.. just solved it by usen `beginSheetModalForWindow:`... perhaps something was wrong with the window being an `NSPanel`??? Dunno... Thanks anyway!